# MassTransit / RabbitMQ - why so many messages get skipped?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm working with 2 .NET Core console applications in a producer/consumer scenario with MassTransit/RabbitMQ.  I need to ensure that even if NO consumers are up-and-running, the messages from the producer are still queued up successfully.  That didn't seem to work with Publish() - the messages just disappeared, so I'm using Send() instead.  The messages at least get queued up, but without any consumers running the messages all end up in the "_skipped" queue.

So that's my **first question**:  is this the right approach based on the requirement (even if NO consumers are up-and-running, the messages from the producer are still queued up successfully)?

With Send(), my consumer does indeed work, but still many messages are falling through the cracks and getting dumped into to the "_skipped" queue.  The consumer's logic is minimal (just logging the message at the moment) so it's not a long-running process.

So that's my **second question**:  why are so many messages still getting dumped into the "_skipped" queue?

And that leads into my **third question**:  does this mean my consumer needs to listen to the "_skipped" queue as well?

---

I am unsure what code you need to see for this question, but here's a screenshot from the RabbitMQ management UI:

[image: RabbitMQ queues]

Producer configuration:

```
    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                      {
                          services.Configure<ApplicationConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationConfiguration)));

                          services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
                          {
                              cfg.AddBus(ConfigureBus);
                          });

                          services.AddHostedService<CardMessageProducer>();
                      })
                      .UseConsoleLifetime()
                      .UseSerilog();
    }

    static IBusControl ConfigureBus(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration>>().Value;

        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(options.RabbitMQ_ConnectionString), h =>
            {
                h.Username(options.RabbitMQ_Username);
                h.Password(options.RabbitMQ_Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, typeof(CardMessage).FullName, e =>
            {
                EndpointConvention.Map<CardMessage>(e.InputAddress);
            });
        });
    }
```

Producer code:

```
Bus.Send(message);
```

Consumer configuration:

```
    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                      {
                          services.AddSingleton<CardMessageConsumer>();

                          services.Configure<ApplicationConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationConfiguration)));

                          services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
                          {
                              cfg.AddBus(ConfigureBus);
                          });

                          services.AddHostedService<MassTransitHostedService>();
                      })
                      .UseConsoleLifetime()
                      .UseSerilog();
    }

    static IBusControl ConfigureBus(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration>>().Value;

        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(options.RabbitMQ_ConnectionString), h =>
            {
                h.Username(options.RabbitMQ_Username);
                h.Password(options.RabbitMQ_Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, typeof(CardMessage).FullName, e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<CardMessageConsumer>(provider);
            });

            //cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, typeof(CardMessage).FullName + "_skipped", e =>
            //{
            //    e.Consumer<CardMessageConsumer>(provider);
            //});
        });
    }
```

Consumer code:

```
class CardMessageConsumer : IConsumer<CardMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<CardMessageConsumer> logger;
    private readonly ApplicationConfiguration configuration;
    private long counter;

    public CardMessageConsumer(ILogger<CardMessageConsumer> logger, IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> options)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.configuration = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CardMessage> context)
    {
        this.counter++;

        this.logger.LogTrace($"Message #{this.counter} consumed: {context.Message}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In MassTransit, the `_skipped` queue is the implementation of the [dead letter queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue) concept. Messages get there because they don't get consumed.

MassTransit with RMQ always delivers a message to an *exchange*, not to a *queue*. By default, each MassTransit endpoint creates (if there's no existing queue) a queue with the endpoint name, an exchange with the same name and binds them together. When the application has a configured consumer (or handler), an exchange for that message type (using the message type as the exchange name) also gets created and the endpoint exchange gets bound to the message type exchange. So, when you use `Publish`, the message is published to the message type exchange and gets delivered accordingly, using the endpoint binding (or multiple bindings). When you use `Send`, the message type exchange is not being used, so the message gets directly to the destination exchange. And, as @maldworth correctly stated, *every* MassTransit endpoint only expects to get messages that it can consume. If it doesn't know how to consume the message - the message is moved to the dead letter queue. This, as well as the poison message queue, are fundamental patterns of messaging.

If you need messages to queue up to be consumed later, the best way is to have the wiring set up, but the endpoint itself (I mean the application) should not be running. As soon as the application starts, it will consume all queued messages.

Comment: _MassTransit with RMQ always delivers a message to an exchange, not to a queue._
So what is the different between sending and publishing a message in MassTransit?

Answer (score 0):

When the consumer starts the bus `bus.Start()`, one of the things it does is create all exchanges and queues for the transport. If you have a requirement that publish/send happens before the consumer, your only option is to run DeployTopologyOnly. Unfortunately this feature is not documented in official docs, but the unit tests are here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Tests/BuildTopology_Specs.cs

The skipped queue happens when messages are sent to a consumer that doesn't know how to process.

For example if you have a consumer that can process `IConsumer<MyMessageA>` which is on receive endpoint name "my-queue-a". But then your message producer does `Send<MyMessageB>(Uri("my-queue-a")...)`, Well this is a problem. The consumer only understands the A, it doesn't know how to process B. And so it just moves it to a skipped queue and continues on.

Comment: In my case, there's only one type of message in this proof-of-concept.  If I have the consumer subscribe to BOTH queues (the standard queue and the "_skipped" queue) it processes all of the messages as fast as they come in.

Comment: you shouldn't have a consumer subscribed to the "_skipped" queue. Or the "_error" queue for that matter. That's an indication that something isn't configured/wired up properly. Typically if you want to re-process stuff on the _error queue, you use the rabbitmq shovel plugin.

Comment: Based on the code I added (above), is there anything in particular that jumps out at you that isn't configured/wired up properly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same queue listens to multiple consumers at the same time